# script in perl to copy directory structure from the source to the destination

Tags: perl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use    File::Copy;
use    strict;

my   $i=  "0";
my   $j=  "1";
my   $source_directory = $ARGV[$i]; 
my    $target_directory = $ARGV[$j];
#print $source_directory,"\n";
#print $target_directory,"\n";

my@list=process_files ($source_directory);
print "remaninign files\n";
print @list;
# Accepts one argument: the full path to a directory.
# Returns: A list of files that reside in that path.
sub process_files {
    my $path = shift;

    opendir (DIR, $path)
     or die "Unable to open $path: $!";

    # We are just chaining the grep and map from
    # the previous example.
    # You'll see this often, so pay attention ;)
    # This is the same as:
    # LIST = map(EXP, grep(EXP, readdir()))
    my @files = 
        # Third: Prepend the full path
        map { $path . '/' . $_}
        # Second: take out '.' and '..'
        grep { !/^\.{1,2}$/ }
        # First: get all files
        readdir (DIR);

    closedir (DIR);

    for (@files) {
        if (-d $_) {
            # Add all of the new files from this directory
            # (and its subdirectories, and so on... if any)
            push @files, process_files ($_);

        } else { #print @files,"\n";
          # for(@files)
        while(@files) 
        {  
        my $input= pop @files;
        print $input,"\n";
        copy($input,$target_directory);

             }
  }
      # NOTE: we're returning the list of files
   return @files;
  }
}
```

This basically copies files from source to destination but I need some guidance on how to 
copy the directory as well. The main thing to note here is no CPAN modules are allowed except copy, move, and path

Comment: If you cannot use CPAN modules, that doesn't mean you cannot use their implementation. Look at [Directory::Iterator](http://search.cpan.org/~sanbeg/Directory-Iterator-1.001/lib/Directory/Iterator.pm) for example. Do pay credit where credit is due.

Comment: Homework or is there another reason you can't use `cp -r`?

Comment: Also see https://metacpan.org/module/File::Copy::Recursive for reference.

Comment: Its obviously homework. 
Regarding CPAN my tutor said i cant use any module which will make this task fairly trivial.
and just for clarification i am going to site in the reference sheet if i have taken help from here.

Comment: Your instructor will burn in hell. Good thing, too.

Comment: Also i forgot to mention this is the first time i m writing code in perl

Comment: @innaM well in lab we are encouraged to work with each other and get help from any body cause they just give me tick if have done it and understand it.

Comment: The "right" way to do it would probably be to use `rsync`. But of course, since this is homework, I guess you will be forced to do it the "wrong" way... (schools are weird). (The next exercise is doing regular expressions in bash?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of rolling your own directory processing adventure, why not simply use [File::Find](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html) to go through the directory structure for you.

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use :5.10;
use warnings;
use File::Find;

use File::Path qw(make_path);
use File::Copy;
use Cwd;

# The first two arguments are source and dest
# 'shift' pops those arguments off the front of
# the @ARGV list, and returns what was removed

# I use "cwd" to get the current working directory
# and prepend that to $dest_dir. That way, $dest_dir
# is in correct relationship to my input parameter.

my $source_dir = shift;
my $dest_dir   = cwd . "/" . shift;

# I change into my $source_dir, so the $source_dir
# directory isn't in the file name when I find them.

chdir $source_dir
    or die qq(Cannot change into "$source_dir");;

find ( sub {
   return unless -f;   #We want files only
   make_path "$dest_dir/$File::Find::dir" 
       unless -d "$dest_dir/$File::Find::dir";
   copy "$_", "$dest_dir/$File::Find::dir"
       or die qq(Can't copy "$File::Find::name" to "$dest_dir/$File::Find::dir");
}, ".");
```

Now, you don't need a `process_files` subroutine. You let `File::Find::find` handle recursing the directory for you.

By the way, you could rewrite the `find` like this which is how you usually see it in the [documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html):

```
find ( \&wanted, ".");

sub wanted {
   return unless -f;   #We want files only
   make_path "$dest_dir/$File::Find::dir" 
       unless -d "$dest_dir/$File::Find::dir";
   copy "$_", "$dest_dir/$File::Find::dir"
       or die qq(Can't copy "$File::Find::name" to "$dest_dir/$File::Find::dir");
}
```

I prefer to embed my *wanted* subroutine into my `find` command instead because I think it just looks better. It first of all guarantees that the *wanted* subroutine is kept with the `find` command. You don't have to look at two different places to see what's going on.

Also, the `find` command has a tendency to swallow up your entire program. Imagine where I get a list of files and do some complex processing on them. The entire program can end up in the `wanted` subroutine. To avoid this, you simply create an array of the files you want to operate on, and then operate on them inside your program:

```
...
my @file_list;

find ( \&wanted, "$source_dir" );

for my $file ( @file_list ) {
    ...
}

sub wanted {
    return unless -f;
    push @file_list, $File::Find::name;
}
```

I find this a programming abomination. First of all, what is going on with `find`? It's modifying my `@file_list`, but how? No where in the `find` command is `@file_list` mentioned. What is it doing?

Then at the end of my program is this `sub wanted` function that is using a variable, `@file_list` in a global manner. That's bad programming practice.

Embedding my subroutine directly into my `find` command solves many of these *issues*:

```
my @file_list;

find ( sub {
    return unless -f;
    push @file_list;
}, $source_dir );

for my $file ( @file_list ) {
    ...
}
```

This just looks better. I can see that `@file_list` is being manipulated directly by my `find` command. Plus, that pesky *wanted* subroutine has disappeared from the end of my program. Its' the exact same code. It just looks better.

---

Let's get to what that `find` command is doing and how it works with the `wanted` subroutine:

The `find` command finds each and every file, directory, link, or whatnot located in the directory list you pass to it. With each *item* it finds in that directory, it passes it to your *wanted* subroutine for processing. A `return` leaves the *wanted* subroutine and allows `find` to fetch the next item.

Each time the *wanted* subroutine is called, `find` sets three variables:

- `$File::Find::name`: The name of the item found with the full path attached to it.
- `$File::Find::dir`: The name of the directory where the item was found.
- `$_`: The name of the item without the directory name.

In Perl, that `$_` variable is very special. It's sort of a default variable for many commands. That is, you you execute a command, and don't give it a variable to use, that command will use `$_`. For example:

```
print
```

prints out `$_`

```
return if -f;
```

Is the same as saying this:

```
if ( -f $_ ) {
    return;
}
```

This `for` loop:

```
for ( @file_list ) {
   ...
}
```

Is the same as this:

```
for $_ ( @file_list ) {
    ...
}
```

Normally, I avoid the default variable. It's global in scope and it's not always obvious what is being acted upon. However, there are a few circumstances where I'll use it because it really clarifies the program's meaning:

```
return unless -f;
```

in my *wanted* function is very obvious. I exit the *wanted* subroutine unless I was handed a file. Here's another:

```
return unless /\.txt$/;
```

This will exit my *wanted* function unless the *item* ends with '.txt'.

I hope this clarifies what my program is doing. Plus, I eliminated a few bugs while I was at it. I miscopied `$File::Find::dir` to `$File::Find::name` which is why you got the error.

Comment: your first part of the code works perfectly but if you could write comments or explain wht you are doing there as i m Beginner i can understand half of it but not fully.

Comment: find ( sub {
   return unless -f;   #We want files only
   make_path "$dest_dir/$File::Find::dir" 
       unless -d "$dest_dir/$File::Find::dir";
   copy $_, $dest_dir/$File::Find::name
       or die qq(Can't copy "$File::Find::name" to "$dest_dir");
}, $source_dir);                                                                           Can anybody pls explain whts happening here i m struggling and hw are copying without even using source directory

Comment: The `find` command is a bit of a strange module. The _wanted_ subroutine is called for each and every file in the directory tree. Each time the _wanted_ subroutine is called, three variables are set: `$File::Find::$name` is set to the full name of the file, `$File::Find::dir` is set to the name of the directory that file is in, and `$_` is set to the name of the file itself. When the _wanted_ subroutine is called, it is in the directory of that file. Thus, you can access the file via `$_`. Thus, `return unless -f` means `return unless -f $_` which means skip this because it's not a file.

Comment: @dhillon - I completely rewrote my post, plus fixed a bug in my program. Read it again and see if what is going on is clearer.

Comment: W Thanks for reply now i understand. and if i need to ignore sumbolic links its done by default i think and if i want to print a message everytime i get a symbolic links. and same with permissions print message

Comment: Take a look at the [Perl Tests Perldoc page](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html). It can be tricky to find because it's called `-X`. This will show you all of the various file tests. `-f $file` tests to see if it's a plain file. That's what I'm doing. To test for a symbolic link you need to say `if ( -l $file ) {`. If you find a symbolic link, you may be on your own. You need to do `symlink` to create the symbolic link (rather than a copy), but you'll have to figure out exactly how that should be made.

Comment: Thanks heaps i just needed to ignore the symbolic links means dont copy them or ignore them and print a message symbolic link is ignored